# microSD Class 4 card in SPI mode returns 0x000000021F after `CMD8`

Tags: fpga, sd

I am trying to read an microSD card through an unbranded SD slot and a Basys3 FPGA. The microSD card, Kingston microSD HC 8GB Class 4, is used via an SD card adapter, also Kingston.

I am having trouble with getting past `CMD8` of the initialization process. After I sent `CMD0` it responded with `0x01` which is normal. After `CMD0` I sent the `CMD8` command; it responded with `0x000000021F`. I wasn't able to find anything related to this code in any documentation.

To test, I tried using a SanDisk Ultra SDHC 32GB Class 10 with the same code. It successfully initialized.

Other things I have tried:

- [Sending Dummy Clocks before and after command with `CS` HIGH](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/303745/sd-card-initialization-problem-cmd8-wrong-response) .
- Always / Not Always Sending `SCLK`.

Please help.

**Waveforms**

The first one shows all of the initialization process. `SD_CD` is Card Detect (Active Low) and `SD_WP` is Write Protect (Active Low). `SD_CLK` is running at 390 kHz, 256 times slower than `_cpuClock`. Please note that the `SD_MISO`, `SD_CD`, `SD_WP` and `_cpuClock` are all simulated manually (i.e. doesn't receive any signal from the SD module). After card is detected, 1 millisecond is waited, followed by 74 `SD_CLK`'s.

[image]

The second image is a zoom in of `CMD0` and its response.

[image]

The third image is a zoom in of `CMD8` and its response.

[image]

The final image is a zoom in of `CMD55` and its response.

[image]

**Update 1** (Prior to @Annoymous Answer) I managed to get my hands on a couple more cards. After testing it seems that only SanDisk Class 10 SDHC (both SD and microSD) returns an initialization finished state. The Kingston Class 4 SDHC SD returns a timeout after `CMD0` while the Kingston Class 4 SDHC microSD returns a `0x000000021F`. Changing the adapter made no difference in all cases. In the image below, the successful ones are in green and the unsuccessful ones are in red.

[image]

**Update 2** (Response to @Annoymous Answer) After changing `MOSI` from `posedge` to `negedge`, the Kingston Class 4 SD card seems to initialized (which was previously timeouted). However, the Kingston Class 4 microSD card still respondsed with `0x000000021F`.

Comment: Both are SDHC, right? Are they both capable of the same class of operation? Sounds like the adapter is the difference. Any other adapters handy?

Comment: Do you send enough dummy clocks prior to initialization?

Comment: @JimmyB I sent 74 clocks prior to initialization. I will update my answer with the simulated waveform.

Comment: @jonk I updated the class of each of the cards. Does class effects operation? I know that there are SDv1 and SDv2, but I am not aware how this is related to Class 4/Class 10. Regarding your other question, no other adapters are available.

Comment: @krismath I wish I were expert in any of this, but unfortunately I'm not. You probably know a fair bit more than I do. But sometimes it helps to hear someone else's thoughts and questions when tracking something like this, so I offered a few that came to mind. That's about my limit, though, without spending a lot more time getting up to speed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attached CMD8 picture shows normal response 1AA (2.7 - 3.6 V, and check pattern AA).

Several notes on things I see:

- do not start command immediately after you activate CS. Wait 8 spare clock cycles, and only then start the command;
- same at the end. Do not deactivate CS just after you think you got complete response for the command. Perform 8 more spare clock cycles before you deactivate CS;
- I am not sure but pictures show that you put data onto the SD-card inputs on positive edge of the SD-card clock. As I recall SD-card latches data on positive edge of its clock, thus putting data there at the same time may violate timing. In my implementation, if I recall properly, I put data onto SD-card input lines on negedge, so that it samples it on next posedge.

Comment: Actually the `CMD8` response was manually simulated -- this wasn't the actual SD's response. I will try what you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, more cards seems to have initialized after `posedge` is set to `negedge`. More dummy clocks are next in list!

Comment: Unfortunately, after giving it more dummy clocks and setting `CS` according to you answer, the SD card still responds with `0x000000021F`

Comment: Ok, then I would do the following: (1) did you check if this card is operational at all? Try it with windows or linux machine. I do not see it from your post; (2) take either real waveforms from the SD-card interface, or perform simulation to see the waveforms and timing of them towards the card.

Comment: It seems that while the 'faulty' card is operational on a standard, commercial microSD card reader, the card failed to operate in my situation. I am clueless and would probably leave it at that; however if anybody is interested in the code, please feel free to visit https://github.com/kkalavantavanich/SD2017 .

Comment: I have the same situation with Samsung evo 64GB sdxc. SDIO mode without problem but in SPI mode it responded with 0x21F after I send CMD8.

Comment: Did the cart return successful R1 response? If you have already investigated your issue and having simulation of your code or measurements of real implementation please start new question.